# SSRS Report Does Not Show Up in Profiler Trace

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-profiler

I have written an SSRS Report and everything works fine within the Visual Studio Solution. When I try to view the report within the browser, all of the parameter fields and columns display, but no data is pulled. There are no errors when running the report and when I run a SQl Server Profiler trace, nothing is there. Any ideas?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: IE 11 - but using Compatibility View

Comment: By any chance do you declare any of the parameters in the SQL code?

Comment: No, I don't declare any variables in the code

Comment: Have you tried running with compatibility view turned off?

Comment: Yes, nothing is still displayed

Comment: Have you tried debugging the report in Visual Studio?

Comment: Have you tried re-deploying the report to your server to ensure it is the same version as BIDS?

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine in VS..Tried re-deploying a few times and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: It kind of sounds like the datasource isn't connecting properly. Have you tried redeploying the datasource or check in the report server that the datasource connects properly?

Answer (score 0):

In browser Click on report's arrow to see drop down menu, then click `Manage`, then go to `Parameters` tab and set them up.

Comment: All of the parameters, data source, and datasets are set-up

Comment: In Report Server too (I mean in browser)? If yes, then maybe you pass wrong value as parameter.

Comment: Yes, within the browser everything is set-up (after clicking 'Manage')